# How do you reference Dojo 1.8 files directly in XPages Domino 9 preview?

Tags: dojo, xpages

I'm wondering how to access dojo 1.8 directly in XPages in the Domino 9.0 Beta Preview.

For instance in the Dojo Docs I see:

This is of course for mobile controls but I don't want to use XPages Mobile controls, I'm looking to access Dojo 1.8 itself and do it manually.

Thanks!

====
Per Answered my question just fine.  Below is a code snippet that I ended up with in case future people are interested.

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:metaData name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"> </xp:metaData>
    <xp:metaData name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> </xp:metaData>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/mobile/themes/iphone/iphone.css"> </xp:styleSheet>

    <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.mobile"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.mobile.parser"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.mobile.ScrollablePane"></xp:dojoModule>

</xp:this.resources>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `/.ibmxspres/dojoroot`. It always points to the latest Dojo release and should therefore point to 1.8 in Domino 9.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with both of the Domino servers I tried (8.5.3 and 9.0) but for me it only works if I add /xsp at the beginning: `/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/`.